# Wt build examples fails

Tags: c++

Debian 8, C++11 and Boost libraries installed:

From what I've read the examples get built all at once.

try_compile() I believe there is a way to enable .c files (and .cpp), I don't think I have done that yet.

crypt not found - is this OpenSSL it's looking for?

Admission of guilt: I haven't worked with C++ in many many years, I've been scripting in PHP with MVC frameworks but I'd like to do more real programming!

I installed the libraries with apt, and I'm using Netbeans with a default "new project from existing sources" on the example directory.

Here's the cmake output:

```
cd '/home/perry/NetBeansProjects/examples'
/usr/bin/cmake  -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG="-g3 -gdwarf-2" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-g3 -gdwarf-2" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
*** Not building widget gallery; C++11 required (gcc > 4.6 + set WT_CPP_11_MODE=-std=c++0x or MSVS >= 2012)
-- Looking for crypt
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.cmake:56 (try_compile):
  Unknown extension ".c" for file

    /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c

  try_compile() works only for enabled languages.  Currently these are:



  See project() command to enable other languages.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  blog/CMakeLists.txt:30 (CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS)


-- Looking for crypt - not found
-- Looking for crypt in crypt
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CheckLibraryExists.cmake:52 (try_compile):
  Unknown extension ".c" for file

    /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c

  try_compile() works only for enabled languages.  Currently these are:



  See project() command to enable other languages.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  blog/CMakeLists.txt:32 (CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS)


-- Looking for crypt in crypt - not found
-- ** Not building codingview example: requires a multi-threaded build.
-- ** Not building broadcast feature example: requires a multi-threaded build.
-- ** Not building serverpush feature example: requires a multi-threaded build.
-- ** Not building socketnotifier feature example: requires a multi-threaded build.
-- ** hello-widget set example requires the built-in http... Skipping.
-- ** Not building filetreetable example: requires boost_filesystem library.
-- ** Not building gitmodel example: requires boost_filesystem library.
-- ** Not building mandelbrot example: requires Wt::WRasterImage.
-- ** Not building onethread example: requires a (ironically) a multi-threaded build.
-- ** Not building simplechat example: requires a multi-threaded build.
-- ** Not building style example: requires WRasterImage.
-- ** Not building wt-homepage example: requires boost_filesystem library.
-- ** Not building wtwithqt example.
--    wtwithqt example requires a Qt4 installation.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/perry/NetBeansProjects/examples/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

CMAKE FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 355ms)
```

Comment: Sorry - I thought I was already on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Have you installed prerequisites? `apt-get install build-essential cmake gcc`?

Comment: Yes - Wt, build essentials, cmake, gcc, g++, c++11, boost - all installed via apt-get.